# Counting epimorphism from $(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}})^*$ and $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $n=q_1....q_n$ where $q_i$is a prime power, then by chinese remainder theorem we have :
    $$ \left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{ Z}}\right)^*\cong \left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{q_1\mathbb{ Z}}\right)^* \times....\times \left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{q_n\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$$
    Since $q_i$ is a prime power $\left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{q_i\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$ has even order and i think this imply that we can find epimorphism. 
    the conclusion of the exercise is that there are $2^n -1$ non trivial epimorphisms but i can't prove it. The case where $n=1$ it's trivial and maybe i can try over induction. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Hom commutes with finite products. All but one homomorphism is also an epimorphism.

Comment: The prime powers must be odd.